# WSO2 ESB URL parsing issue

Tags: url, wso2, esb

I am receiving HTTP/SOAP request with some query parameters. Those query parameters are in repeated format as key=value as /q=key1=value1&key2=value2 etc...
I would like to retrieve all the keys from above URL and check if they are valid or not.
1. Is there any way to define global array which can hold these keys
2. How to validate if keys are present or not. Does ESB supports java "contains" API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are doing a GET request..
You can retrieve all the query parameters in a sequence.

eg:
For a request url; http:// localhost:8280/getSimpleQuote?symbol=IBM

`<property name="symbol" expression="$url:symbol"/>` will return the symbol 'IBM'.
After getting all  keys, you can validate them

Comment: Take an example, my GET request URL is [Link](http://localhost:8280/services/MyProxyService?q=(activity:INPUT||step:First)&start=1&rows=20)                        I would like to check if my URL has following keys present or not : activity, step. How can I retrieve and validate.

Comment: @MadhupSrivastava yes you can do, like as i mentioned above. First read the q param from the url, <property name="qParam" expression="$url:q"/> this will keep the value of "q" filed..from that check whether preferred input is there or not.

Comment: Can you please advise on how to check with some sample.

Comment: You can write a simple proxy or API and in the insequence you can use property mediators to pick values. Check this samples, http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Getting+Started+with+REST+APIs

Answer (score 1):

you can get the query parameters with the xpath expression get-property{'uri.var.xxx'} with xxx is the name of the query parameter you need to get.

When a resource is defined with a URL mapping, only those requests that match the given URL mapping will be processed by the resource. Alternatively one could configure a resource with a URI template. A URI template represents a class of URIs using patterns and variables. Some examples of valid URI templates are given below.

/order/{orderId}
/dictionary/{char}/{word}
All the identifiers within curly braces are considered variables. A URL that matches the template “/order/{orderId}” is given below.

/order/A0001
In the above URL instance, the variable orderId has been assigned the value “A0001”. Similarly following URL adheres to the template “/dictionary/{char}/{word}”.

/dictionary/c/cat
In this case the variable “char” has the value “c” and the variable “word” is given the value “cat”. When a resource is associated with a URI template, all requests that match the template will be processed by the resource. At the same time ESB will provide access to the exact values of the template variables through message context properties. For an example assume a resource configured with the URI template “/dictionary/{char}/{word}”. If the request “/dictionary/c/cat” is sent to the ESB, it will be dispatched to the above resource and we will be able to retrieve the exact values of the two variables using the get-property XPath extension of WSO2 ESB: